# Overiding CrudeRepository save() error with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i am trying to overide save function using Hibernate and JpaRepository, but every time i try to run program i get error saying

> Error:(15, 23) java: save(com.studapp.students.Student) in com.studapp.students.StudentJpaRepository clashes with save(S) in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository
>     return type java.util.Optional is not compatible with S

Student class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Student")
public class Student implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "STUDENT_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long ID;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lasttName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "dateOfBirth")
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    @Column(name = "JMBAG")
    private String JMBAG;

    @Column(name = "numberOfECTS")
    private Integer numberOfECTS;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Course.class )
    @JoinTable(
            name = "student_course" ,
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID") } ,
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID") }
    )
    private List<Course> courses;

    public Student(){};

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, LocalDate dateOfBirth, String jmbag, Integer numberOfECTS) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.JMBAG = jmbag;
        this.numberOfECTS = numberOfECTS;
    }
//getters and setters
```

Controller class StudentController  :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("student")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
public class StudentController {
private final StudentService studentService;

public StudentController(StudentService studentService){
    this.studentService = studentService;
}
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<StudentDTO> save(@Valid @RequestBody final StudentCommand command){
    return studentService.save(command)
            .map(
                    studentDTO -> ResponseEntity
                            .status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                            .body(studentDTO)
            )
            .orElseGet(
                    () -> ResponseEntity
                            .status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
                            .build()
            );
}
```

Interface for service StudentService :

```
public interface StudentService {
  Optional<StudentDTO> save(StudentCommand command);
}
```

Implementation for service class StudentServiceImpl

```
@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService{

    private static final int YEARS_AFTER_WHICH_TUITION_SHOULD_BE_PAYED = 30;

    private final StudentJpaRepository studentJpaRepository;

    public StudentServiceImpl(StudentJpaRepository studentJpaRepository){
        this.studentJpaRepository = studentJpaRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<StudentDTO> save(final StudentCommand command) {
        return studentJpaRepository.save(mapCommmandToStudent(command)).map(this::mapStudentToDTO);
    }

    private StudentDTO mapStudentToDTO(final Student student){
        return new StudentDTO (student.getFirstName(), student.getLastName(), 
    student.getJMBAG(),student.getNumberOfECTS(), shouldTuitionBePayed(student.getDateOfBirth()));
    }

    private Student mapCommmandToStudent(final StudentCommand studentCommand) {
        return new Student(studentCommand.getFirstName(), studentCommand.getLastName(), 
    studentCommand.getDateOfBirth(), studentCommand.getJmbag(), studentCommand.getNumberOfECTS());
    }
}
```

Interface for JpaRepository :

```
@Repository
public interface StudentJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    Optional<Student> save(Student student);
}
```

And i am using h2 in memory database:
schema.sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Student (
    STUDENT_ID identity,
    JMBAG CHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
    firstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    lastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    dateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL,
    numberOfECTS INT NOT NULL
) ;
```

```
INSERT INTO Student ( firstName, lastName, dateOfBirth, JMBAG, numberOfECTS)
VALUES ('Jhon' , 'Jhonson' , '1993-05-08' , '0024789510' , 121  );
```

Comment: It's not the case for `save` method to return Optional result, it's better to throw an exception if something went wrong during save.

Answer (score 0):

In order to override existing method , **You have to create save method exactly same as there in CrudRepository** .

You can do something like the following :

```
@Repository
public interface StudentJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    <S extends MyEntity> S save(S entity);
}
```

MyCustomRepositoryImpl .java

```
public class MyCustomRepositoryImpl implements StudentJpaRepository {

    @Override
    public <S extends MyBean> S save(S entity) {
       /**
         your custom implementation comes here ...
       */
    }
```

}

Comment: But what if im using Hibernate? In that repository i have a lot of othert methods. Like findStudentByLastName(String lastName) etc. Then i need to write implementation of those methods as well

Comment: Those customs methods are not predefined in CrudRepository . So you can write implemntation class for them easily . Is just the pattern followed so that it will be easy for the user .

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the **save method** to return Optional? Save method returns the saved Item (newly created, or updated).

Optional return means that the value returned could be null. And there is no way that it will return **null** value.

From what understand in your logic, you just need to check for the item if it exists or not based on a unique key (ex: FirstName-LastName-DateOfBirth), and if so return `HttpStatus.CONFLICT`.

Hope this helps